# Is there a way to get "groups of combinations" of lists that don't overlap, and is exhaustive, using itertools on Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, discrete-mathematics

Here's what I mean: if you found all possible 2-element combinations of [1,2,3,4], you would get [1,2], [1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4] and [3,4]

What I want is groups of combinations that don't overlap and include all elements. So for example [[1,2],[3,4]] is an example of one "group", because the elements in both combinations do not overlap, and all possible elements are used. [[1,3],[2,4]] is an example of another "group"

By the way, I'm aware that itertools will allow me to print combinations themselves. So for example, the following code:

```
combinations = itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4], 2)
for c in combinations:
    print(c)
```

will output:

```
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 4)
```

But again, that's just giving me combinations. I want GROUPS of combinations that are mutually exclusive and exhaustive with the elements.

Also, I'm sure I'm not using the proper vocabulary. If there is a formal term for anything I'm describing, I would appreciate learning it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like the [Set Cover Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). If it's the case, it's a [NP-hard problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness).

Comment: Note also than you can't have a solution at each time. Exemple: when your initial set contains an odd number of elements, if you ask for groups of size 2, it's impossible to cover all the set without having an overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These “groups of combinations” might be called `set partitions into parts of size k`.

I assume that `k` is divisor of `n`, so there are `p=n/k` parts.

Now we can recursively  distribute items over parts. To avoid repeated generation of the same partition (like `01 23 45` and `01 45 23`), we should restrict places for leading (the smallest) element of every group.

Here I used `lastfilled` parameter for index of the rightmost filled part, so item 0 always belongs to the 0-th part, item 1 might fall into parts 0 or 1 but not into part 2 and so on. Having intermediate result `01 __ __` we can make only `01 2_ __` at the next level, not `01 __ 2_`.

Note that number of such partitions is

```
NPK(n,k) = n! / ((k!)^p * p!)
```

and grows fast (`280` for `n=9,k=3`, `1401400` for `15/3`). (Found [OEIS sequence A060540](http://oeis.org/A060540))

Python code. I used global lists for parts contents and counts of occupied places in them to save memory, so I have to reset counts to previous state after recursive call.

```
n = 6
k = 2
p = n // k
parts = [[0]*k for _ in range(p)]
cnts = [0]*p

def genparts(m, lastfilled):
    if m == n:
        print(parts)
        return
    for i in range(min(p, lastfilled + 2)):
        if cnts[i] < k:
            parts[i][cnts[i]] = m
            cnts[i] += 1
            genparts(m+1, max(i, lastfilled))
            cnts[i] -= 1

genparts(0, -1)

[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
[[0, 1], [2, 4], [3, 5]]
[[0, 1], [2, 5], [3, 4]]
[[0, 2], [1, 3], [4, 5]]
[[0, 2], [1, 4], [3, 5]]
[[0, 2], [1, 5], [3, 4]]
[[0, 3], [1, 2], [4, 5]]
[[0, 4], [1, 2], [3, 5]]
[[0, 5], [1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[0, 3], [1, 4], [2, 5]]
[[0, 3], [1, 5], [2, 4]]
[[0, 4], [1, 3], [2, 5]]
[[0, 5], [1, 3], [2, 4]]
[[0, 4], [1, 5], [2, 3]]
[[0, 5], [1, 4], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a busy week. This answer was perfect, thanks!

Comment: Hey, can you explain the purpose of the following line:
l = [i for i in range(n)]

Comment: It was an artifact from the first tryout, Removed.

Comment: Alright.

I'm actually struggling to modify your code to make it return a list of lists to me, instead of just printing out the combinations. I added in an additional parameter to the genparts function called myList. And then I changed print(parts) to myList.append(parts). When I call the function on a list, the list just contains the last partition. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: import copy and make `lst.append(copy.deepcopy(parts))` to avoid adding copies of the same object (pointer to `parts`)

Comment: That's my solution. I hope to one day be as amazing as you. Thanks!